# Bipartite network graph with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, bipartite

I have the following data frame:

```
structure(list(X1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L
), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), class = "factor"), 
    X2 = structure(c(1L, 6L, 8L, 10L, 12L, 13L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 6L, 
    7L, 9L, 10L, 12L, 13L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 10L, 12L, 13L, 4L, 1L, 
    6L, 12L, 13L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 2L, 
    3L, 11L, 12L, 13L), .Label = c("I1", "I10", "I11", "I12", 
    "I13", "I2", "I3", "I4", "I5", "I6", "I7", "I8", "I9"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("X1", 
"X2"), row.names = c(NA, -40L), class = "data.frame")
```

Where in X1 is the person number and in X2 the group to which the person belongs to. One person can be in different groups.
Now I want to draw a line from each person to each group he belongs to. With `plot()` I solved it this way:

```
plot(0, xlim=c(0,1), ylim=c(0,1), type="n", axes=FALSE, xlab="", ylab="")

factor.to.int <- function(f) {
  (as.integer(f) - 1) / (length(levels(f)) - 1)
}

segments(factor.to.int(data$X1), 0, factor.to.int(data$X2), 1, col=data$X1)
axis(1, at = seq(0, 1, by = 1 / (length(levels(data$X1)) - 1)), labels = levels(data$X1))
axis(3, at = seq(0, 1, by = 1 / (length(levels(data$X2)) - 1)), labels = levels(data$X2))
```

The result looks like this:
[image: bipartite graph]

Now I wondering how I can do this with ggplot2?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Cross-reference: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1457599/602276

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A simple `ggplot2` version of your graph is possible by using `geom_segment()` and transforming the data much like you did for the base graphics version. I've also included an arguably more polished version, using some of the more advanced customization options in ggplot2.

```
# Using ggplot2 version 0.9.2.1
library(ggplot2)

dat$x1_norm = rangeTransform(as.integer(dat$X1))
dat$x2_norm = rangeTransform(as.integer(dat$X2))

dat$y1 = 0
dat$y2 = 1

# Simple version.
p1 = ggplot(dat, aes(x=x1_norm, xend=x2_norm, y=y1, yend=y2, colour=X1)) +
     geom_segment(size=1.2) +
     scale_colour_brewer(palette="Set1", name="Person")

ggsave(plot=p1, filename="plot_1.png", height=3.5, width=6)
```

[image]

```
# Fancy version.
# Create separate data.frames to manually specify axis ticks and axis text.
axis_1 = data.frame(x=rangeTransform(as.integer(unique(dat$X1))),
                    y=0, label=as.character(unique(dat$X1)))

axis_2 = data.frame(x=rangeTransform(as.integer(unique(dat$X2))),
                    y=1, label=as.character(unique(dat$X2)))

p2 = ggplot(data=dat) +
     theme_bw() +
     theme(axis.title=element_blank()) +
     theme(axis.text=element_blank()) +
     theme(axis.ticks=element_blank()) +
     theme(panel.grid=element_blank()) +
     geom_segment(aes(x=x1_norm, xend=x2_norm, y=y1, yend=y2, colour=X1),
                  size=1.2) +
     geom_segment(x=0, xend=1, y=0, yend=0, size=0.7) +
     geom_segment(x=0, xend=1, y=1, yend=1, size=0.7) +
     scale_colour_brewer(palette="Set1", name="Person") +
     scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-0.2, 1.2), expand=c(0, 0)) +
     geom_segment(data=axis_1, aes(x=x, xend=x, y=y, yend=y-0.025), size=0.7) +
     geom_segment(data=axis_2, aes(x=x, xend=x, y=y, yend=y+0.025), size=0.7) +
     geom_text(data=axis_1, aes(label=label, x=x, y=y - 0.075)) +
     geom_text(data=axis_2, aes(label=label, x=x, y=y + 0.075))

ggsave(plot=p2, filename="plot_2.png", height=3.5, width=6)
```

[image]

Comment: Just for completeness rangeTransform is: `rangeTransform = function(x) (x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x))`