# Simplest way to plot changes in ranking between two ordered lists in R?

Tags: r, graph, plot, ranking, bipartite

I'm wondering if there is an easy way to plot the changes in position of elements between 2 lists in the form of a directed bipartite graph in R. For example, list 1 and 2 are vectors of character strings, not necessarily containing the same elements:

```
list.1 <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g")

list.2 <- c("b","x","e","c","z","d","a")
```

I would like to generate something similar to:

[image: The sort of output I am after]

I've had a slight bash at using the igraph package, but couldn't easily construct what I would like, which I imagine and hope shouldn't be too hard.

Cheers.

Comment: Your question is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1457599/602276 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/13244122/602276

Comment: Indeed, I saw these, but I guess I assumed there would be a function that I was unaware of that would make it trivial to plot and customize.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a simple function to do what you want. Essentially it uses `match` to match elements from one vector to another and `arrows` to draw arrows.

```
plotRanks <- function(a, b, labels.offset=0.1, arrow.len=0.1)
  {
  old.par <- par(mar=c(1,1,1,1))

  # Find the length of the vectors
  len.1 <- length(a)
  len.2 <- length(b)

  # Plot two columns of equidistant points
  plot(rep(1, len.1), 1:len.1, pch=20, cex=0.8, 
       xlim=c(0, 3), ylim=c(0, max(len.1, len.2)),
       axes=F, xlab="", ylab="") # Remove axes and labels
  points(rep(2, len.2), 1:len.2, pch=20, cex=0.8)

  # Put labels next to each observation
  text(rep(1-labels.offset, len.1), 1:len.1, a)
  text(rep(2+labels.offset, len.2), 1:len.2, b)

  # Now we need to map where the elements of a are in b
  # We use the match function for this job
  a.to.b <- match(a, b)

  # Now we can draw arrows from the first column to the second
  arrows(rep(1.02, len.1), 1:len.1, rep(1.98, len.2), a.to.b, 
         length=arrow.len, angle=20)
  par(old.par)
  }
```

A few example plots

```
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
plotRanks(c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g"),
          c("b","x","e","c","z","d","a"))
plotRanks(sample(LETTERS, 20), sample(LETTERS, 5))
plotRanks(c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g"), 1:10) # No matches
plotRanks(c("a", "b", "c", 1:5), c("a", "b", "c", 1:5)) # All matches
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

[image: comparing ranks]

Comment: That is absolutely perfect. Thank you. I would have thought there would be a function as part of an existing package that did exactly this.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a solution using `igraph` functions.

```
rankchange <- function(list.1, list.2){
    grp = c(rep(0,length(list.1)),rep(1,length(list.2)))
    m = match(list.1, list.2)
    m = m + length(list.1)
    pairs = cbind(1:length(list.1), m)
    pairs = pairs[!is.na(pairs[,1]),]
    pairs = pairs[!is.na(pairs[,2]),]
    g = graph.bipartite(grp, as.vector(t(pairs)), directed=TRUE)
    V(g)$color =  c("red","green")[grp+1]
    V(g)$label = c(list.1, list.2)
    V(g)$x = grp
    V(g)$y = c(length(list.1):1, length(list.2):1)
    g
}
```

This builds and then plots the graph from your vectors:

```
g = rankchange(list.1, list.2)
plot(g)
```

[image]

Adjust the colour scheme and symbolism to suit using options detailed in the igraph docs.

Note this is not thoroughly tested (only tried on your sample data) but you can see how it builds a bipartite graph from the code.

Comment: (+1) Nice pic, though seems awfully lots of coding for such a simple plot

Comment: The code doesn't do any plotting :) The plotting is a one-liner! The trick is that the code builds the correct data structure for the problem - the OP might want that (although its not our job to second-guess OPs). I think you could probably chop a few lines out of it.

Comment: Ooo thanks for this. This will definitely be useful.

Answer (score 8):

With ggplot2:

```
v1 <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g")
v2 <- c("b","x","e","c","z","d","a")

o <- 0.05
DF <- data.frame(x = c(rep(1, length(v1)), rep(2, length(v2))),
                 x1 = c(rep(1 + o, length(v1)), rep(2 - o, length(v2))),
                 y = c(rev(seq_along(v1)), rev(seq_along(v2))),
                 g = c(v1, v2))

library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
ggplot(DF, aes(x=x, y=y, group=g, label=g)) +
  geom_path(aes(x=x1), arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.02,"npc")), 
            size=1, color="green") +
  geom_text(size=10) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        panel.grid = element_blank())
```

[image: resulting graph]

This can of course be wrapped in a function easily.

Comment: Had to stare at this for a while before I realised the "match" between v1 and v2 was being effectively done by the `group` aesthetic of `ggplot`! Neat.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a generalization of nico's result for use with data frames:

```
plotRanks <- function(df, rank_col, time_col, data_col, color_col = NA, labels_offset=0.1, arrow_len=0.1, ...){

  time_vec <- df[ ,time_col]
  unique_dates <- unique(time_vec)
  unique_dates <- unique_dates[order(unique_dates)]

  rank_ls <- lapply(unique_dates, function(d){
    temp_df <- df[time_vec == d, ]
    temp_df <- temp_df[order(temp_df[ ,data_col], temp_df[ ,rank_col]), ]
    temp_d <- temp_df[ ,data_col]
    temp_rank <- temp_df[ ,rank_col]
    if(is.na(color_col)){
      temp_color = rep("blue", length(temp_d))
    }else{
      temp_color = temp_df[ ,color_col]
    }
    temp_rank <- temp_df[ ,rank_col]

    temp_ls <- list(temp_rank, temp_d, temp_color)
    names(temp_ls) <- c("ranking", "data", "color")
    temp_ls
  })

  first_rank <- rank_ls[[1]]$ranking
  first_data <- rank_ls[[1]]$data
  first_length <- length(first_rank)

  y_max <- max(sapply(rank_ls, function(l) length(l$ranking)))
  plot(rep(1, first_length), 1:first_length, pch=20, cex=0.8, 
       xlim=c(0, length(rank_ls) + 1), ylim = c(1, y_max), xaxt = "n", xlab = NA, ylab="Ranking", ...)

  text_paste <- paste(first_rank, "\n", "(", first_data, ")", sep = "")
  text(rep(1 - labels_offset, first_length), 1:first_length, text_paste)
  axis(1, at = 1:(length(rank_ls)), labels = unique_dates)

  for(i in 2:length(rank_ls)){
    j = i - 1
    ith_rank <- rank_ls[[i]]$ranking
    ith_data <- rank_ls[[i]]$data
    jth_color <- rank_ls[[j]]$color
    jth_rank <- rank_ls[[j]]$ranking
    ith_length <- length(ith_rank)
    jth_length <- length(jth_rank)
    points(rep(i, ith_length), 1:ith_length, pch = 20, cex = 0.8)
    i_to_j <- match(jth_rank, ith_rank)
    arrows(rep(i - 0.98, jth_length), 1:jth_length, rep(i - 0.02, ith_length), i_to_j
      , length = 0.1, angle = 10, col = jth_color)
    offset_choice <- ifelse(length(rank_ls) == 2, i + labels_offset, i - labels_offset)
    text_paste <- paste(ith_rank, "\n", "(", ith_data, ")", sep = "")
    text(rep(offset_choice, ith_length), 1:ith_length, text_paste)
  }
}
```

Here's an example using a haphazard reshape of the `presidents` dataset:

```
data(presidents)
years <- rep(1945:1974, 4)
n <- length(presidents)
q1 <- presidents[seq(1, n, 4)]
q2 <- presidents[seq(2, n, 4)]
q3 <- presidents[seq(3, n, 4)]
q4 <- presidents[seq(4, n, 4)]
quarters <- c(q1, q2, q3, q4)
q_label  <- c(rep("Q1", n / 4), rep("Q2", n / 4), rep("Q3", n / 4), rep("Q4", n / 4))
q_colors <- c(Q1 = "blue", Q2 = "red", Q3 = "green", Q4 = "orange")
q_colors <- q_colors[match(q_label, names(q_colors))]

new_prez <- data.frame(years, quarters, q_label, q_colors)
new_prez <- na.omit(new_prez)

png("C:/users/fasdfsdhkeos/desktop/prez.png", width = 15, height = 10, units = "in", res = 300)
  plotRanks(new_prez[new_prez$years %in% 1960:1970, ], "q_label", "years", "quarters", "q_colors")
dev.off()
```

This produces a time series ranking plot, and it introduces color if tracking a certain observation is desired:

[image]