# How to properly create this kind of plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to show the connections between a number of people, organizations or whatever:

```
   Var1 Var2 Freq
1     F    A    5
2     F    B   38
3     B    C   10
4     E    C   28
5     A    D    8
6     B    D   21
7     A    E   50
8     A    F   34
9     D    F   50
10    E    F   14
```

[image]

I couldn't find any examples for this kind of plot, so I started from scratch. However, I'm struggling with the labels for the frequency values. Any ideas how to fix that?

MWE:

```
### Sample data ###

# Gerate names
names <- LETTERS[1:6]

# Generate all possible permutations
df = expand.grid(rep(list(names), 2))
rownames(df) <- NULL

# Drop some of the permutations
df <- df[df$Var1 != df$Var2, ]
df <- df[-sample(1:nrow(df), nrow(df) * 2/3), ]

# Add a column with random frequency values
df$Freq <- sample(1:50, nrow(df), replace=T)

### Prepare sample data for ggplot ####

# Add a column with the row numbers (used for grouping)
df$Pair <- 1:nrow(df)

# Convert data frame to long format
df.from <- df[, -which(names(df) %in% c("Var2"))]
df.from$Type <- "From"
colnames(df.from) <- c("Name", "Freq", "Pair", "Type")

df.to <- df[, -which(names(df) %in% c("Var1"))]
df.to$Type <- "To"
colnames(df.to) <- c("Name", "Freq", "Pair", "Type")

df2 <- rbind(df.from, df.to)

### Plot ###

library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

p <- ggplot()
p <- p + geom_text(aes(x = "From", y = names, label = names), hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5)
p <- p + geom_text(aes(x = "To", y = names, label = names), hjust = 0, vjust = 0.5)
p <- p + geom_line(data = df2, aes(x = Type, y = Name, group = Pair))
p <- p + geom_text(data = df2[df2$Type == "To", ], aes(x = Type, y = Name, group = Pair, label = Freq), hjust = 3, vjust = 0.5)
p <- p + scale_y_discrete(name = "", limits = rev(factor(names, levels = sort(names))))
p <- p + scale_x_discrete(name = "", limits = c("From", "To"))
p
```

Comment: You might find useful these three resources regarding so-called Tufte bump charts or slopegraphs:(1)  http://charliepark.org/a-slopegraph-update/
(2) http://learnr.wordpress.com/2009/05/06/ggplot2-bump-chart/; (3) 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25781284/simplest-way-to-plot-changes-in-ranking-between-two-ordered-lists-in-r

:

Comment: Not going to be easy without calculating the positions of each label, storing them in df2, finding the collisions, and moving them apart. I suspect you wanted to avoid that.

Comment: Sorry, but this isn't really a duplicate question. It's related, yes, but it doesn't answer how to properly add the labels.

Answer (score 3):

to me the request:

> to show the connections between a number of people, organizations or whatever

sounds like a desire to graph the the network plot. Using the `network` package:

```
#Construct a sparse graph
m<-matrix(rbinom(100,1,1.5/9),10)
diag(m)<-0
g<-network(m)
#Plot the graph
plot(g)
```

You could get the following
[image: Sample network plot]

Alternatively, this may be more relevant to your problem, you may consider making use of the `qgraph` package. For example the code below:

```
require(qgraph)
set.seed(1)
adj = matrix(sample(0:1, 10^2, TRUE, prob = c(0.8, 0.2)), nrow = 10, ncol = 10)
qgraph(adj)
title("Unweighted and directed graphs", line = 2.5)
```

Would return this beautiful network graph:
[image: qgrapph example]

If you are you looking for more examples just refer to [this excellent page](http://sachaepskamp.com/qgraph/examples#qgraph) by Sacha Epskam on how to use `qgraph`.

Comment: Thanks, qgraph looks like a nice alternative to Graphviz! (Looks like there's no way around Gimp in my case.)